# Eclipse workspace fails loading, project is not found

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp, workspace

Yesterday I deleted a project in an eclipse workspace... and I guess eclipse did not close down properly because I can't open that workspace.

The errorlog is telling me that a project is missing. Full error stacktrace can be found here: http://pastebin.com/duyawcMM

How can I fix this? Already tried to create new workspace and import the existing projects.. but then I can't export my RCP application?

Answer (score 1):

Try starting your ecplise with `clean` option as `eclipse -clean`.

Comment: Doesn't work... and deleting the .metadata just just makes you need to import the projects again... which is the same as creating a new workspace... that failed so I guess deleting the .metadata will fail as well :(

Comment: Try one other thing. Check if there are any entries in `.lock` file within `.metadata`. If yes, clean them and restart. Also it keeps the history in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.history` folder. Try moving last day folders and restart. I am suggesting some clean up work arounds which might help restoring your workspace.

Comment: Well thank you for the info! but I first tried to delete the .metadata and import the projects from the same workspace... it failed before but now it worked.. have no idea how, but everything builds, deploys and even past bugs are fixed in the app! Thank you so much for your time. And I will keep this -clean parameter in mind! Thanks

Comment: Good to know it worked for you. May be lean fixed the files in the first run and started working after restart. If you think it was helpful, please accept to close the thread.